# Android support:design won't import

Tags: android

Trying to install the design support libraries to use TabLayout, but despide a successful gradle sync they do not appear in the external libraries section nor are they usable. Here are the relevant sections of the build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "aetherum.com.spectrumwatchface"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile project(':spectrum')
}
```

As you can see, I've installed a lot to try to fix this and I'm no longer sure what is necessary. My SDK is as updated as it could be

Comment: you should keep a similar version throughout all support libraries. I can see different version such as `23.2.1`,`23.3.0` and `23.1.0` . Choose same version for all

Answer (score 0):

try this one as your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.test"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
       'proguard-rules.pro'
               }
           }
       }

dependencies {
           compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
           testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
           compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.4@aar') {
               transitive = true
           }
           compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
           compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
           compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```